# what is wrong with this piece of code of javascript inheritance?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

```
function condition(){ 
  this.expression = ""; 
  this.toString = function(){
    return this.expression;
  }
};

function and(first, second){
    this.expression = first + " and " + second;
}

function nop(){};
nop.prototype = condition.prototype;

and.prototype = new nop();

var a =new and(1,2);

console.log(a.toString());
```

it is expected to see "1 and 2" as output but this is what happened:
"[object Object]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are transfering the prototype of `condition` to `nop`'s prototype. The problem is that your `condition.toString` is not declared in the prototype... Here:

```
function condition(){ 
  this.expression = ""; 

};
  condition.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.expression;
  }
function and(first, second){
    this.expression = first + " and " + second;
}

function nop(){};
nop.prototype = condition.prototype;

and.prototype = new nop();

var a =new and(1,2);

console.log(a.toString());
```

OR

```
function condition(){ 
  this.expression = ""; 
  this.toString = function(){
    return this.expression;
  }
};

function and(first, second){
    this.expression = first + " and " + second;
}

function nop(){};
nop = condition;

and.prototype = new nop();

var a =new and(1,2);

console.log(a.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

you aren't overriding the toString method, because the constructer of condition is never called! try doing this;

```
condition.prototype.toString=function(){
    return this.expression;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing strings into your and function, as at the moment you are trying to concatenate integers to a string   `var a =new and("1","2");`

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
function condition(){ 
  this.expression = ""; 
};    

condition.prototype.toString = function(){
   return this.expression;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem here is you are mixing two inheritance patterns (http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-patterns/) the pseudo-classical with the functional patterns.

You can create an object by adding methods on the constructor function:

```
function MyClass() {
    var privateProperty = 1;
    this.publicProperty = 2;

    function pivateMethod() {
        // some code ...
    }

    this.publicMethod = function() {
        // some code ...
    };
}

// inheritance
function SubClass() {
    MyClass.call(this);

    this.newMethod = function() { };
}
```

Here when you create a instance of this class you are creating every method again.

Then you have the prototype pattern:

```
function MyClass() {
    this._protectedProperty = 1;
    this.publicProperty = 2;
}
MyClass.prototype._protectedMethod = function() {
    // some code ...
};
MyClass.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
    // some code ...
};

// inheritance
function SubClass() {
    MyClass.call(this);
}
SubClass.prototype = new MyClass();
SubClass.prototype.newMethod = function() { };

// OR
function SubClass() {
    MyClass.call(this);
}

function dummy() { }
dummy.prototype = MyClass.prototype;
SubClass.prototype = new dummy();
SubClass.prototype.newMethod = function() { };
```

Yhen you must choose one of those two patterns, not both·

I've fixed your code on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dz6Ch/